# Issues with bundle exec rake test

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails, using Michael Hart's book on Rails tutorial for my learning. I've done `gem install bundler` and also `bundle install` to get all my gems specified in the `gemfile`;

But when I run `bundle exec rake test` to test my application it shows system cannot find the path specified.
I've written my test code in `controller_test.rb` with `require test_helper` included as part of the test code.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you post your `controller_test` code snippet and also the path of `controller_test.rb` file

Comment: And post the exact error/stacktrace.

Comment: the part of controller_test.rb is C:\Users\Rollson\Desktop\sample_app\test\controllers, the error message is: The system cannot find the path specified. thanks

Comment: am having problems posting the controller snippet. its not well formatted when i post it and i've not  seen any add attachment icon in the add comment box

Comment: require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def setup
    @base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get home" do
    get :home
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Home | #{@base_title}"
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get :help
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Help | #{@base_title}"
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get :about
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "About | #{@base_title}"
  end

end